# Trying to use jq to format json data on one line

Tags: json, export-to-csv, jq

The output below is my json output from my curl query.   I have tried multiple jq filters to try to get to a result that looks like
**interfaceId,vendor,addresses**

from my json/curl output, After applying "jq" filters, I am only getting:

```
eth1

eth1

eth1

Apple

BB Technologies (Limited)

null

Ipaddress#1

Ipaddress#2

Ipaddress#3
```

I want the output to be:

`interfaceId,vendor,addresses`        for each record returned by curl/json

Can someone help me out on this

```
{
  "deviceId": "75c2fde3-4b5a-4faf-a24d-d8019e8911e1",
  "macTable": [
    {
      "interfaceId": "eth1",
      "addresses": [
        "192.168.5.101"
      ],
      "mac": "3c:15:c2:c3:f0:e0",
      "vendor": "Apple",
      "vlan": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "device": {
        "id": null,
        "connected": null,
        "enabled": null,
        "authorized": null,
        "ipAddress": null,
        "identification": {
          "id": null,
          "type": null
        },
        "overview": {
          "status": "unknown"
        }
      },
      "site": null
    },
    {
      "interfaceId": "eth1",
      "addresses": [
        "192.xxx.x.1"
      ],
      "mac": "xx:83:c4:01:ac:5d",
      "vendor": "BB Technologies (Limited)",
      "vlan": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "device": {
        "id": null,
        "connected": null,
        "enabled": null,
        "authorized": null,
        "ipAddress": null,
        "identification": {
          "id": null,
          "type": null
        },
        "overview": {
          "status": "unknown"
        }
      },
      "site": null
    },
    {
      "interfaceId": "eth1",
      "addresses": [
        "192.xxx.x.100"
      ],
      "mac": "9f:25:0b:4b:32:73",
      "vendor": null,
      "vlan": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "device": {
        "id": null,
        "connected": null,
        "enabled": null,
        "authorized": null,
        "ipAddress": null,
        "identification": {
          "id": null,
          "type": null
        },
        "overview": {
          "status": "unknown"
        }
      },
      "site": null
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "total": 3,
    "count": 20,
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jq -r '.macTable[] | [.interfaceId, .vendor, .addresses[]] | @csv' x.json
```

output is something like

```
"eth1","Apple","192.168.5.101"
"eth1","BB Technologies (Limited)","192.xxx.x.1"
"eth1",,"192.xxx.x.100"
```

and document is https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions

Comment: Thank you.   I see what my problem was now.   Thanks for the quick reply.